# Why can't I sort a list right after I make it?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a set I want to make into a sorted list. I run:

```
sorted_list=list(my_set).sort()
```

but this returns `none`, even when both `list(my_set)` and `my_set` are both nonempty. On the other hand this:

```
sorted_list=list(my_set)
sorted_list.sort()
```

works just fine.

Why is this happening? Does python not allow methods to be called on objects directly returned by constructors?

Comment: the same reason that `a = my_list.append(b)` doesn't work like people think it does.

Comment: You _can_ sort a list right after you make it. Your code already does exactly that. It's just that `sorted_list` is a reference to the value returned by `sort`, which is `None`, so you don't end up with any reference at all to the actual sorted list. But it still exists (or did, before the GC cleaned it up before you didn't keep a reference to it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.sort()` sorts the list in place and returns `None`. You need to use the `sorted()` function here.

```
>>> a = [3, 2, 1]
>>> print a.sort()
None
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> sorted(a)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

It's simple:

- `sort()` makes sorting in place and returns `None`
- `sorted()` returns a sorted copy

Here's a quote from [How To/Sorting - Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/):

> Python lists have a built-in sort() method that modifies the list
>   in-place and a sorted() built-in function that builds a new sorted
>   list from an iterable.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for this:

```
sorted_list = sorted(list(my_set))
```

Or even simpler:

```
sorted_list = sorted(my_set)
```

`sort()` sorts the list in place and returns `None`, and that's what will be stored in `sorted_list`. That's not what we expected.

On the other hand, `sorted()` returns a new sorted list with the elements it received as a parameter (it can be a list or a set: in fact, any iterable), and that's what gets assigned to `sorted_list` - just what we wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Because the `sort` method changes the list *in-place*. What do you want is the `sorted` function, which returns a sorted list:

```
sorted_list = sorted(my_set)
```

The `sorted()` function does not touch its argument, since it makes a copy of it. On the other hand, the `sort` method directly changes the original list and returns `None`.